# Cardinality of initial segments

Tags: set-theory

I've seen in several places that that given a well-ordered set, $X$, any initial segment $S = \{x | x < a\}$  may not be *order* isomorphic to $X$.

Is it still possible that there is a non-order-preserving bijection between $S$ and $X$?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I believe that it could be the case, but a paper I am reading (https://www.nature.com/articles/s42256-018-0002-3?WT.feed_name=subjects_statistics) asserts otherwise.

In particular, I was thinking that it must be the case that some initial segment of a well-ordering of the real numbers has cardinality strictly greater than countable, but if the cardinality of that segment is not the cardinality of the continuum, then this would resolve with continuum hypothesis (which is impossible).

Comment: @AsafKaragila The linked question and answers do not resolve the question from my comment regarding whether all initial segments of a well-ordering of the reals are countable.

Comment: Surely a well-ordering of type $\omega_1$ is either $\omega+1$, in which case the union of a countable set with a singleton is uncountable; or there are at least two countable infinite ordinals, in which case there is a bijection between them. I am sure that a paper in Nature is not making assertion like that one. It is true, however, that *finite* well-orders are not in bijections with any of their proper initial segments.

Comment: Ah in the proof they actually do consider only limit ordinals, so I see now how the linked question helps. Thank you.